# Hook to time knitr chunks

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I would like to time knitr chunks and record how long it took to render them using comments in LaTeX output.

I've tried the following hook:

```
 now = Sys.time()
 knit_hooks$set(timeit = function(before) {
     if (before) { now <<- Sys.time() }
     else {
         paste("%", sprintf("Chunk rendering time: %s seconds.\n", round(Sys.time() - now, digits = 3))) 
     }
 })
```

And it does produce the correct comment with timing but the problem is that it's wrapped in kframe which results in ugly gaps in the LaTeX output:

```
\begin{kframe}

% Chunk rendering time: 12.786 seconds.

\end{kframe}
```

Is there a way to produce unwrapped comments?

Comment: FWIW, it was cross-posted at https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1042

Comment: Do you have a MWE indicating the _ugly gaps_?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
local({
  now = Sys.time()
  knit_hooks$set(timeit = function(before) {
    if (before) {
      now <<- Sys.time()
    } else {
      x = round(Sys.time() - now, digits = 3)
      x = sprintf("%% Chunk rendering time: %s seconds.", x)
      paste('\\end{kframe}\n', x, '\n\\begin{kframe}')
    }
  })
})
```

It is a hack, though. Basically you escape the LaTeX comment from the `kframe` environment.